# Alterar Fragment a partir de clique

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer com que meu aplicativo exiba um novo Fragment a partir de um clique. A mensagem é impressa no console quando eu clico no botão, mas o fragment não se altera.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);

    FAB = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
            System.out.println("Clique!");
        }

    });
}
```

Estou fazendo algo errado?

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda!

==========

Quando eu inicio meu aplicativo ele mostra uma listagem (em CardViews) de uma série de registros retornados pelo meu WebService.

Nesta mesma tela é exibido um FloatActionButton que é responsável por chamar a view do formulário. Foi para criar a ação deste FAB que eu abri esta pergunta. Atualmente, o método onCreateView do meu Fragment que possui o FAB e os CardViews está da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classrooms, container, false);

    FAB = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NewClassroomFragment newClassroomFragment = new NewClassroomFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.classrooms, newClassroomFragment);
            ft.commit();
            System.out.println("Clique!");
        }

    });
}
```

Até aqui está tudo funcionando perfeitamente, graças às respostas já recebidas: quando eu clico no botão, a minha view de listagem é substituída pela view do formulário.

Neste formulário há uma ImageView para a qual eu criei um ClickListener que tem a responsabilidade de voltar para a página de listagem com os CardViews. Essa imagem é um botão de voltar. O método para fazer isso é idêntico ao anterior:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_classroom, container, false);

    BACK = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.back);
    BACK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClassroomsFragment classroomFragment = new ClassroomsFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.replace(R.id.classrooms, classroomFragment);
            ft.commit();
            System.out.println("Voltar!");
        }

    });

    return v;
}
```

Este "botão" de voltar está funcionando perfeitamente, exceto pelo fato de que, atrás dos CardViews é possível ver os CardViews antigos que foram carregados antes de se chamar o formulário.

O fluxo é esse:

Tela Inicial com CardViews -> Formulário -> Tela Inicial com CardViews.

A imagem abaixo mostra o que está ocorrendo de fato:
[image: CardViews com Problemas]

Perceba que nos espaços que separam um CardView e outro é possível ver os cards carregados logo na excecução do app.

Comment: De uma olhada em beginTransaction dos Fragments, com ele voce consegue trabalhar dinamicamente, mais tarde posto pra voce como faz

Answer (score 2):

Na sua Activity crie um método desta forma:

```
public void openFragment()
{
    Fragment fr = new Fragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

O seu metodo de click deve estar assim:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     openFragment();
     System.out.println("Clique!");
 }
```

Para os fragment, não devemos trocar o view, e sim trocar a Fragment.

Para entender melhor de uma olhada na [documentação clicando aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Já que o método `onClick()` está no *fragment* falta `getActivity()` antes de `openFragment()`, seria assim: `getActivity().openFragment();`

Comment: Se eu coloco getActivity().openFragment(); é retornado o erro "Cannot resolve method 'openFragment()' ".

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: o openFragment() é o metodo que voce implementou ! onde ele está ? na mesma classe que você chama?

Comment: E necessário um cast na getActivity() para a Activity que voce implementou

Comment: Sim Thiago. Ele está na mesma classe.

Tentei assim:

                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.class_fragment, tab2);
                ft.commit();

O problema aí é que o AndroidStudio me retorna um erro porque não consegue encontrar o class_fragment. Se eu faço R.layout.class_fragment ele encontra, mas avisa que espera um resource do tipo id.

Comment: Então o **class_fragment** é o container que irá receber seu Fragment no caso um **FrameLayout**. Quando voce criou o xml você declarou um **FrameLayout**?? No caso é o id dele que vai no lugar do **class_fragment**

Comment: Já estou ficando meio desnorteado aqui. Já tentei de todas essas formas. Estou com problemas na hora de passar os parâmetros para fazer o replace. Depois de dar uma alterada no código agora eu consigo encontrar o id do FrameLayout que será substituído. Por exemplo: ft.replace(R.id.classrooms, tab2);

O problema é que agora me dá erro no segundo parâmetro porque diz que é necessário o import android.supportv4.app.Fragment.

Se eu faço isso, todas as outras instruções anteriores dão erro.

Comment: então utilize o **getSupportFragmentManager() ** ao invés de ** getFragmentManager** .  Como não sabemos o que está usando em seu projeto, isto ocorre mesmo! Tenha calma, leia a documentação e o mais importante **tente entender o que está fazendo** Qualquer coisa estamos aqui para ajudar

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Consegui realizar a transaction da forma que você me instruiu. Acontece que agora eu consigo exibir outro fragment, mas o fragment antigo continua aparecendo debaixo dessa nova view. O que devo colocar no código para que o fragment antigo (ou view antiga) simplesmente deixem de existir?

Comment: Poderia mostrar seu código completo? Nunca vi isto acontecer!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Dá só uma olhada no meu edit.